# How to use websockets for my JSON streambuilder?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have set up the streambuilder and stream async functions,but i do not know how to use it properly as it needs websockets. How can i use websockets in these case to fetch my Json data from my server?

```
Stream<List<Post>> FetchPosts(http.Client client) async* {
  final response = await http.get("$SERVER_IP/api/articles/?format=json");
  final parsed = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  yield parsed.map<Post>((json) => Post.fromJSON(json)).toList();
}

StreamBuilder<List<Post>>(
          stream: FetchPosts(http.Client()),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

            return snapshot.hasData ? PostsList(posts: snapshot.data)
                :
            Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.pink,valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.pinkAccent)));

          },
        ),
```

**Class**

```
class Post {
  final String id;
  final String author;
  final String caption;


  Post({this.id, this.author,this.caption});


  factory Post.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMapPost) {
    return Post(
      id: jsonMapPost['id'] as String,
      caption: jsonMapPost['caption'] as String,
      author: jsonMapPost['author'] as String,);}}
```

**Json data**

```
[{"id":"a4d64194-3d81-4a4e-b7e6-6fce36fea793","author":"a94d4433-ffaf-4af1-aa8d-67ac75bf2e53","caption":"this is caption",]}
```

Comment: Recently I've been working with streams from [Lichess ](https://lichess.org), my code should work with other WS servers, if you still need to review other options, I could test my code with your server and if it works then I could show it to you.

Comment: send me the code plase.The one below did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) package that provides StreamChannel wrappers for WebSocket connections.

With it you `fetchPosts` function can turn into something like that:

```dart
Stream<List<Post>> fetchPosts() {
  final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse("$SERVER_IP/api/articles/?format=json"));
  return channel.stream.map((r) => parse(r));
}
```

If your websocket server emits message in this format:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "a4d64194-3d81-4a4e-b7e6-6fce36fea793",
    "author": "a94d4433-ffaf-4af1-aa8d-67ac75bf2e53",
    "caption": "this is caption"
  }
]
```

then your `parse` function can look like that:

```dart
List<Post> parse(String message) {
  final json = jsonDecode(message) as List<dynamic>;
  return json.map((j) => Post.fromJSON(j as Map<String, dynamic>)).toList();
}
```

Comment: Can you modify it for FetchPosts() function? First line works but Stream and websockets are way different than standard Future so i do not know how to work on it.

Comment: @umarbeyoglu it depends on the format of WS message that your server emits. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I provided some details on my class and json data.Hopefully it will help you

Comment: `Connection to 'http://$SERVER_IP:0/api/articles/?format=json#' was not upgraded to websocket`

Comment: Do you actually have the websocket support on server?

Comment: never checked it.I will look into that.

Comment: i guess it is solved on flutter and now it is server issue now. So i see this as case closed.